# Using implode to output numbered list from array?

Tags: php, arrays, implode

I've been trying to figure this out for a couple hours now, but as a PHP newbie I'm struggling to wrap my head around it.

I am trying to pass multiple (numbered) items to an Amazon API. My array ($asins) is filled with all the stings I need.

Here's my array:

```
$asins = array('STRING_1', 'STRING_2', 'STRING_3');
```

I need to output in the following format:

```
ASINList.ASIN.1=STRING_1&ASINList.ASIN.2=STRING_2&ASINList.ASIN.3=STRING_3
```

The array will always contain 25 of these strings.

I realise this is probably incredibly simple, but any hints would be appreciated. I like to learn!

Comment: Please show us your array + your current code

Comment: Post your attempts. What you have tried so far

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code should done it.
Array key always start at '0'. in you case, you need '1'

```
$array = array('STRING_1', 'STRING_2', 'STRING_3');
$URLparameters = array();

foreach( $array as $key => $value ){
    $newkey = $key + 1;
    $URLparameters[] = "ASINList.ASIN.".$newkey."=".$value;
}

$result = implode("&", $URLparameters);
```

[EDIT] based on the idea of Emiliano Sangoi

```
$a = array('ASINList.ASIN.1', 'ASINList.ASIN.2', 'ASINList.ASIN.3');
$b = array('STRING_1', 'STRING_2', 'STRING_3');
$c = array_combine($a, $b);

echo http_build_query($c);
```

Comment: Perfection. Thank you for explaining the answer, too... I can see the logic behind this :)

Answer (score 2):

If you keep your arguments in the following way:

```
$asins = array(
        "ASINList.ASIN.1" => 'STRING_1',
        "ASINList.ASIN.2" => 'STRING_2',
        "ASINList.ASIN.3" => 'STRING_3'
    );
```

The only thing that you need to do is:

```
echo http_build_query($asins);
```

Answer (score 0):

[PHP implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) is for simple arrays (1, 2, 3...) but yours is a complex array (f1 = v1, f2 = v2), so use a for loop to control how the string is generated, e.g.:

```
$output = "";

for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {

    $output .= "ASINList.ASIN.$i" . "=" . $array[$i] . "&";
}

echo $output;
```

Comment: Result of this code is : ASINList.ASIN.0=STRING_1&ASINList.ASIN.1=STRING_2&ASINList.ASIN.2=STRING_3&
because of the array key and it add an extra '&' at the end